# Compare drawing with original

Tags: ios, uiimageview

For the last week I've been attempting to write some code in which I'd be able to trace an image and compare it with the original by pixel color count. So far the only two definite thing working is the drawing and pixel count (which obviously returns 0 since the rest isn't working)

To make the UIImageView of the drawing into a PNG for comparison I take a screenshot.However, I'm trying to call the saved drawing (screenshot) immediately after the save for a pixel color count and comparison. This whole process is not working whatsoever.

The pixel count code asks for a PNG at the moment,so I'm trying to work around that.

Is there maybe an easier way to do this whole process instead of first taking a screenshot, then calling it and then getting the pixel color count? I'm trying to make the code as simple as possible by comparing only two colors.

Any help would be appreciated. I would post code, but I'd rather get a fresh take on this since I've tried many different ways already. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: post code and/or describe your different attempts it's more likely to elicit a response. what do you mean by "pixel color count" - histogram? average?

Comment: By pixel color count i mean, counting all blue pixels within a specific picture, for example.

I've tried comparing the entire picture to picture but I felt it was too much unnecessary code so I went down to just pixel amount comparison. I think if I could just call the saved PNG forth, then it would work...